# Не обновляются данные на странице (Ajax) после отправки формы

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ajax, django

У меня товары корзины находятся в сессии, с неё и берутся когда рендерится страница. При отправке формы (заказать), на сервере у меня очищается корзина. Но эта функция не видит что корзина пустая и меняет $('body').html на тот что и был. Только после перезагрузки страницы - товары оттуда пропадают. Как фиксить? Серв на Django, если что

```js
function orderFromBasket() {
    let form = $('#order-from-basket');
    form.submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: $(this).attr('method'),
            url: $(this).attr('action'),
            data: new FormData(this),
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function(html) {
                $('body').html(html);
                $('#order_success').show();
                $('#order_address').val(' ');
            }
        })
    });
}
```